# Changing Dynamic UIView subviews with single Tap in UIGestureRecognizer Method

Tags: xcode, uiview, tap

UPDATE:Solved issue, see below!

The situation: I have several dynamically loaded UIViews on a UIScrollView in a nib.

Expected behavior: I want to single TAP any one of the UIViews and it will change background color to indicate it was tapped. If it was already tapped it should then change back to its initial look.

I have set up a UITapGesture recognizer on each of the UIViews and here is the selector method where I am doing the behavior. I have confused myself. I apologize for the sketchy logic here (it is a ruff draft). I have set up a isTapped BOOL set to "NO" initially in the init in the file.

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
isTapped = !isTapped;

UIView *v = gestureRecognizer.view;

NSInteger currentIndex = [studentCellArray indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:v];

if (oldIndex != currentIndex) {
    isTapped = YES;
}

//check to see if obj in array then switch on/off
if ([tappedViewArray indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:v] != NSNotFound) {
    oldIndex = currentIndex;
}
if (currentIndex == v.tag) {
    isTapped = !isTapped;
}

if (isTapped) {

    [tappedViewArray addObject:v];
    [super formatViewTouchedNiceGrey:v];

}else{

    [tappedViewArray removeObject:v];
    [super formatViewBorder:v];
}

if (currentIndex == oldIndex) {
    isTapped = !isTapped;
}
```

}

Actual Behavior: After Tapping the First UIView it selects fine and changes, a second tap will change it back, however after successive taps it stays selected. Also, if you select a UIView and go to another view - you have to double tap the successive views.

I would like to just tap once to turn off or on any of the UIViews in the scrollview.

UPDATE: Well, after some Hand writing and other vain attempts at trying to focus on this issue ---- I have solved it this way and it BEHAVES properly!

here is my solution:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

isTapped = !isTapped;

UIView *v = gestureRecognizer.view;

NSInteger currentIndex = [studentCellArray indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:v];


if (((isTapped && currentIndex != oldIndex) || (!isTapped && currentIndex != oldIndex)) && [tappedViewArray indexOfObject:v] == NSNotFound) {

    oldIndex = currentIndex;

    [tappedViewArray addObject:v];
    [super formatCornerRadiusWithGreyBackgrnd:v];

} else {

    [super formatViewBorder:v];
    [tappedViewArray removeObject:v];

}
```

}

So I hope this helps someone with this issue.

The key was to check for the isTapped and indexes being not equal AND the view object NOT being in the array I was assembling to indicate items touched/Tapped....